# Crash when opening connection to Microsoft SQL with Glassfish

Tags: java, sql-server, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, jdbc

I am developing JavaEE 8 app with GlassFish 5.0.0 and I want to access database that resides in Microsoft SQL server. I attached Microsoft SQL driver 7.0 jre8 in Maven.

When I deploy the app and try to open a page which accesses the database, I got a crash. StackTrace below.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.internal.spec.TlsMasterSecretParameterSpec.getExtendedMasterSecretSessionHash()[B
at com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsMasterSecretGenerator.engineGenerateKey(TlsMasterSecretGenerator.java:107)
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.generateKey(KeyGenerator.java:546)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateMasterSecret(Handshaker.java:1174)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.calculateKeys(Handshaker.java:1120)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1126)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:351)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:984)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:919)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1756)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2391)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at datas.DatabaseDatas.getLelang(DatabaseDatas.java:19)
at org.apache.jsp.company.halaman_005futama_005fcompany_jsp._jspService(halaman_005futama_005fcompany_jsp.java:595)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The code that triggers the crash is here:

```java
public class DatabaseDatas {
private final static String sqlconn = "jdbc:sqlserver://<redacted>;" +
        "databaseName=dbName";

/**
 * Gets Lelang data in LelangList
 * @return Data in LelangList table
 */
public static ResultSet getLelang(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection sqlconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlconn,"sa","password"); //this is the one which trigger the crash
        sqlconnection.isValid(0); //ignore this
        Statement sta = sqlconnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM ListLelang";
        return sta.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException|SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I use Jetbrains Intellij IDEA 2018.2.3 as IDE and set JDK 1.8.0_151 as Project SDK. I've also set javax.sql.DataSource and java.sql.driver in JDBC Connection Pool in GlassFish 5 Admin panel.

I have no idea why this happens. I can't find my error anywhere on the Internet.
Please help me resolve this problem. I can provide more info if needed (as long as it's not personal info). Thank you.

EDIT: Actually I forget to test the connection pool. After I try to 'ping' via Glassfish 5 Admin Panel, I got the same error as the one in the stacktrace above.
[Glassfish admin panel error when pinging to MSSQL connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs1rb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to ditch Glassfish completely (because as far as I see, Glassfish is quite out of date at the time of this writing) and using [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/) (webservice version) as a web servlet.

And it works just fine, even with latest JDK (1.8.0_181)! No more errors regarding MSSQL anymore.

Answer (score 1):

With Java EE you shouldn't open the database connection to your SQL-Server manually with the `DriverManager`. The application server (Glassfish) in your case is responsible for opening the connections and pooling them.

As you said you already configured Glassfish for the `DataSource` and the `JDBC Connection Pool` you won't need to do this in your code again. You can now use the `DataSource` with injecting it via `@Resource(lookup="JNDI_NAME_OF_YOUR_DATASOURCE") DataSource dataSource;` in your code (EJB or CDI) and work with it. You get the `Connection` with `dataSource.getConnection();`.

If you plan to use the `EntityManager` and work with `JPA`, you need a `persistence.xml` file in your application in the following directory: `src/main/resources/META-INF` and it could look like the following:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="prod" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>JNDI_NAME_OF_YOUR_CONFIGURED_DATASOURCE</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

With this setup you can now inject the `EntityManager` in your CDI or EJB bean with `@Resource EntityManager entityManager;` and use it.

With this approach, you make sure that the application server is managing every infrastructure-related stuff (dealing with a database) and you can focus on your business logic.

The following tutorial might help you further: https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/resource-creation002.html

Comment: See my edited post. Actually, I got the same error (`NoSuchMethodError`) when I try to 'ping' said connection in Glassfish Admin panel. Maybe it has to do with my IDE?